# Why the objects are moving to the first moving object instead moving on the waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToMove;
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public float rotSpeed;
    public bool random = false;
    public int currentCurvedLinePointIndex;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numofposbetweenpoints;
    private bool getPositions = false;
    int randomIndex;
    int curvedPointsIndex;
    public float delay;
    private float[] startTimes;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
            objectsToMove[i] = Instantiate(objectsToMove[i], parent.transform);
            objectsToMove[i].name = "Platfrom";

            curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();

            if (curvedLinePoints != null && curvedLinePoints.Count > 0)
            {
                objectsToMove[i].rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;
            }
        }

        startTimes = new float[objectsToMove.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < startTimes.Length; i++)
        {
            startTimes[i] = Time.time + (Random.value * delay);
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        

        if (lineRenderer.positionCount > 0 && getPositions == false && CurvedLineRenderer.linesSet)
        {
            pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
            numofposbetweenpoints = curvedLinePoints.Count;

            if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
            {
                foreach (Transform objToMove in objectsToMove)
                {
                    objToMove.position = pos[index];
                }
            }

            getPositions = true;
        }

        if (go == true && lineRenderer.positionCount > 0)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int c = 1;
    void Move()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Time.time < startTimes[i]) continue;

            Vector3 newPos = objectsToMove[i].position;
            float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            bool stillTraveling = true;
            while (stillTraveling)
            {
                Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);

                distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
                if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
                {
                    // when you hit a waypoint:
                    if (goForward)
                    {
                        bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                        if (!atLastOne)
                        {
                            index++;
                            counter++;
                            if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                            {
                                c++;

                                counter = 0;
                            }
                            if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                            {
                                c = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else { index--; goForward = false; }
                    }
                    else
                    { // going backwards:
                        bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                        if (!atFirstOne)
                        {
                            index--;

                            counter++;
                            if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                            {
                                c++;

                                counter = 0;
                            }
                            if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                            {
                                c = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else { index++; goForward = true; }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stillTraveling = false;
                }
            }

            objectsToMove[i].position = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I have 3 objects to move. The first one start moving after 5 seconds and moving on the pos array positions.

Then the second object is start moving after 7 seconds but now instead moving also on the pos array positions the second object is reaching the first moving object and then move with him together.

The same thing happens with the last third object to move from the List objectsToMove.

I can't figure out why they are reaching the first object that move instead that each one will move on the pos array positions ?

Not sure if it's the delay line inside the Move function that make the problem :

```
if (Time.time < startTimes[i]) continue;
```

Or maybe the loop in the Move function :

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
```

Comment: This is still the same conceptually-backwards approach from your last question. Why aren't you using an approach based on the accepted answer from that question? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/191643/how-can-i-add-to-the-waypoints-multiple-objects-to-move-between-the-waypoints

Comment: To repeat what I said before - waypoints should not move objects. Objects should move themselves along waypoints. You're confusing yourself and making your code needlessly complicated by using this backwards approach.

Comment: @Kevin I tried your answer 2 days ago but I had to change it to work with my waypoints and it didn't work with the speed. I'm getting the waypoints from a LineRenderer lines count positions.  The object/s are moving along the LineRenderer lines positions.  I packed my very small project of the waypoints at this link :https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtV2OUzEcRzrxXOZ53REKxs59JLD?e=MOWwoS

Comment: @Kevin there are 3 scripts. The waypoints another script that build create the waypoints positions from the LineRenderer and another script that make the lines of the LineRenderer smooth so the objects can be move at any speed on the positions of the line renderer.  And with my waypoints script I calculate the positions and can move the objects along the waypoints at any speed.  The idea to make multiple objects to move along the waypoints and adding delay came after.

Comment: @Kevin You solution 2 days ago is fine but it didn't work with my waypoints system. I move objects over LineRenderer positions. I'm getting the LineRenderer positions from lines I draw and then move the objects over this positions in the array pos.

Comment: The solution I posted for your previous question could be adapted to work with points from a line renderer, and it will make your life easier.

Comment: @Kevin Ok I'm trying again the solution in the question 2-3 days ago.  I also marked as answered.  but I'm getting error on the line : Vector3 waypoint = waypoints[waypointIndex]; on the right side : CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Waypoints' both mono are in the same script file right ? but I'm getting this error. before even making any changes it to fit it to the linerenderer and other stuff.

Comment: @Kevin Or the second mono should be on the moving object prefab so if I have 5 moving objects each one of them will have his own control ? I tried it too and getting the same error. but should I put the second mono on the prefab of the moving object/s ?

Comment: @Kevin I still don't understand how this two mono's show be working. and still getting this error on this solution : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/191643/how-can-i-add-to-the-waypoints-multiple-objects-to-move-between-the-waypoints

Comment: Is that because you don't have a separate `index` variable for every object?

Comment: @YasarNadil Sorry, there was a mistake in the answer to that question; I've updated it. Use `waypoints.GetWaypoint(waypointIndex)`, not `waypoints[waypointIndex]`.

Comment: @Kevin How can I make that it will move back only if a flag is set to true when running the game? I added a flag name goBack on the WaypointFollower script and at this place I want it to move back only if the flag is true if the flag false move between all the waypoints but stop at the last one and don't move back.  waypointIndex = (waypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Count;

Comment: `if (goBack) { //code } else { //code }`

Comment: Working thanks.